# Testing AWS Lambda functions locally - invalid function name?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, npm-install, aws-cli

So, I'm finally at the point where I can test my first Lambda function locally. As background, I've installed the AWS CLI under MacOS 10.14.2 (Mojave) and am able to access my AWS account. I've successfully zipped up my Lambda function and used 'aws lambda create-function' to deploy it.

I've installed aws-lambda-local (https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-lambda-local) using 'npm install -g aws-lambda-local'.

But when I invoke the following from the Lambda function root:

```
lambda-local -l index.js -e event.json
```

I get the following error:

```
Invalid function name. It should be accessible from invocation place
```

Would someone please tell me why this is happening? I mean, the function name is most definitely valid.

Totally confused here!

Comment: Are you using aws-lambda-local or just lambda-local? They don't have the same CLI inputs.

Comment: Yes, it was my mistake. I needed a `-f` option!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the aws-lambda-local docs, there is no `-l` option. Use `-f` or `--function` to specify the file with the lambda function